# Issue with Relative layout in android-event listener: one child's listener is getting applied to all children

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout, event-listener

I am having my views inside a relative layout. I did an on-click listener for one of the child views, but the action is getting applied for all the children of the relative layout. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

code posting related to issue may help in getting quick answer. Answer may depend on implementation context.